# R: How to remove helper text in pie chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following pie chart in R. How do I remove the "0/100", "25", "50", "75" from around the circle?

[image]

I've already tried this:

```
theme(axis.text = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

The issue appears when I add in the line with geom_text()

```
geom_text(aes(label = paste0(round(percent), "%")), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), check_overlap = T)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try `+ theme_void()`

Comment: That worked! Thank you @markus

Comment: Feel free to self-answer your question if you found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
+ theme_void()
```

Thank you @markus